# How to try accessing webpage again after http errors in python for loop

Tags: python, http, reddit

[Example of 522 error when I go to the webpage manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfdOx.png)

[Example of 525 error when I go to the webpage manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5aGm.png)

[Example of 504 error when I go to the webpage manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVLyn.png)

I am running the following for loop which goes through a dictionary of subreddits(key) and urls (value). The urls produce a dictionary with all posts from 2022 of a given subreddit. Sometimes the for loop stops and produces a 'http error 525' or other errors.

I'm wondering how I can check for these errors when reading the url and then try again until the error is not given before moving to the next subreddit.

```
for subredd, url in dict_last_subreddit_posts.items(): 
    print(subredd)
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    dict_last_posts[subredd] = page
```

I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: Are you concerned only with 525 status codes, or do you want to retry on other status codes as well?

Comment: Which URL generates this error?

Comment: @MichaelRuth I want to retry on other status codes as well

Comment: Which status codes do you want to retry on?

Comment: Here is an example url. The urls don't always generate an error message. http://api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/submission?title=&size=1000&after=1641016800&before=1672552799&subreddit=Ohio

Comment: I want to retry on error 504, 522, and 525. There may be other error codes I haven't seen yet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48730866/python-urllib-error-httperror-http-error-525-origin-ssl-handshake-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unwise to indefinitely retry a request. Set a limit even if it's very high, but don't set it so high that it causes you to be rate limited (HTTP status 429). The `backoff_factor` will also have an impact on rate limiting.

Use the `requests` package for this. This makes it very easy to set a custom adapter for all of your requests via `Session`, and it includes `Retry` from `urllib3` which takes care of retry behavior in an object you can pass to your adapter.

```py
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter, Retry

s = requests.Session()
retries = Retry(
    total=5,
    backoff_factor=0.1,
    status_forcelist=[504, 522, 525]
)
s.mount('https://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))

for subredd, url in dict_last_subreddit_posts.items(): 
    response = s.get(url)
    dict_last_posts[subredd] = response.content
```

You can play around with `total` (maximum number of retries) and `backoff_factor` (adjusts wait time between retries) to get the behavior you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can put this code in `try` and `except` block like this:

```
for subredd, url in dict_last_subreddit_posts.items(): 
    print(subredd)
    while True:
        try:
            page = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
            dict_last_posts[subredd] = page
            break # exit the while loop if the request succeeded
        except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
            if e.code == 525 or e.code == 522 or e.code == 504:
                print("Encountered HTTP error while reading URL. Retrying...")
            else:
                raise  # re-raise the exception if it's a different error
```

This code will catch **any** HTTP Error that occurs while reading the URL and check if the error code is `525` or `504` or `525`. If it is, it will print a message and try reading the URL again. If it's a different error, it will re-raise the exception so that you can handle it appropriately.

**NOTE**: This code will retry reading the URL indefinitely until it succeeds or a different error occurs. You may want to add a counter or a timeout to prevent the loop from going on forever in case the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
for subredd, url in dict_last_subreddit_posts.items():
    print(subredd)
    http_response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    while http_response.status != 200:
        if http_response.status == 503:
            http_response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        elif http_response.status == 523:
            #enter code here
        else:
            #enter code here
    dict_last_posts[subredd] = http_response.read()
```

But, Michael Ruth answer is better

Comment: I got the following error with the code you suggested. (I added error 504 in the code chunk)

HTTPError: HTTP Error 504: Gateway Timeout